# Disable ESLint "Quick Fix" suggestions in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint

I am using ESLint in my React project to format and lint my code. I use VSCode as editor, and I find the "Quick Fix" suggestions offered by VSCode quite handy, like "import module" etc. However, after enabling ESLint, the default Quick Fix suggestion of VSCode is replaced by ESLint's Quick Fix suggestions:

[image: eslint-quick-fix-suggestion]

How do I disable this? Please note that I still want ESLint to format and fix my code, but I don't want its quick fix suggestions. Instead I want VSCode to show its original Quick Fix suggestions. Like in above case, I want VSCode to suggest importing `Link` from `react-router-dom` rather than ESlint offering me its own quick fix suggestions (this was happening before enabling ESLint).

Comment: i would like to see vscode quick fix suggestions THEN eslint suggestions this is terrible as it blocks auto imports.  thanks for bringing this up, maybe create a bug on the vscode github

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue with bash scripts. Disabling the [ShellCheck extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=timonwong.shellcheck) solved the issue for me.

Comment: I don't even have that extension installed.